# Factor analysis/PCA for a Likert scale with variable number of responses

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, likert

I am given a Likert-type rating scale which comprises 6 items. Items have a different number of possible scorings, namely:

- Item 1 [0,1,2,3]
- Item 2 [0,1,2]
- Item 3 [0,1,2,3]
- Item 4 [0,1,2,3]
- Item 5 [0,1,2,3,4]
- Item 6 [0,1,2,3,4]

I have a cohort (N=100) of participants with responses to these questionnaire.

**OBJECTIVES**

1. To identify the most informative items (Factor Analysis/PCA)
2. To check explicitly, whether the Item **6** is needed in the questionnaire or might be skipped.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Are any limitations on application of Factor Analysis/PCA to this data set given the fact that not all items have the same range? Should they somehow be normalised?
2. How to check whether some of the items are significant (cannot be removed from the questionnaire?

Comment: Why are you interested in the significance of certain items? Why would you want to eliminate an item from data analysis? OR is this question regarding whether or not you need to ask that question *in the future* (i.e., that is, you are shortening the scale)?

Comment: It is a research question, whether we can remove one (or more) items from the scale. We have collected a unique data set to check this hypothesis. Empirically, we observed that one item almost always remains untouched (score zero), thus the question is do we really need to keep a particular item?

Comment: Pt1. If you want to treat your scales as interval, just do classic FA on correlations. Pt2: unclear what you mean by "significant" and why you want to remove nonsignificant. Are you expecting one or two factors in your FA? Will you want to keep only items loaded heavily by the factor(s), Etc. How do you see your task and process?